# Magento2.1 not loading css, js and admin panel after installation

Tags: admin, javascript, css, magento-2.1, installation

I have installed magento2.1 CE. And it is not loading css, js and admin panel also.

I have set `web/seo/use_rewrites` to 0, but still admin is not loading.

I have also tried to remove contents under `pub/static (excpt .htaccess)` and changed the recommended path to,

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink to 
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

And also cleared `var` folder. But still nothing happened, no loading of css, js and admin panel.

Also, running this command :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I keep getting this error :

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Locale' not found in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php:64
Stack trace:

0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php(28): Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle->cleanLocale('en_US')
1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Lists.php(80): Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\DataBundle->get('en_US')
2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/Locale.php(42): Magento\Framework\Setup\Lists->getLocaleList()
3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php(107): Magento\Framework\Validator\Locale->isValid('en_US')
4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(257): Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
5 /var/www/html/magento2/v in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Bundle/DataBundle.php on line 64
```

Comment: are you solved this problem ? same issue

Answer (score 2):

Open your console/terminal, and type these commands

1. bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
3. bin/magento setup:di:compile
4. bin/magento cache:flush
5. chmod -R 777 .

Comment: Done that already